Magento 2 and TDD good practices to implement tests
here is my concern, when it comes to testing in Magento 2, I find documentation is quite obselete or very difficult to understand.
If PhpUnit offers ways to test a simple method...I feel like as soon as Magento 2 objects and database are getting involved, everything is getting super duper complicated. So here I am looking for real and working examples about testing, rather we use it for TDD or not, I think test should take a more important part on our development process.
So, here are some use cases I would like to ensure threw working coding examples. I hope some of you may have leads about it.
Use Case number 1 :

Get a product / Change his price / Save the product


Check the expected price has been properly saved.

Use Case number 2 :

Create a product Given a free SKU


Check that the expected product has been properly created.

Use Case number 3 :

Create a product Given a taken SKU


Check that the product can't be created as the sku is already taken

I'm sorry I can't provide any code for this I just have no idea how to start about it. I feel like there might be a data fixture implied somehow...but really no idea...I would appreciate any working exemple in any of these use cases or similar with custom entities.
EDIT : I just tried an example and it's not working or may be i'm just doing everything wrong i don't know.
I have a class method I want to test for the example
class CustomerAction extends AbstractGenericAction implements CustomerActionInterface {



public function __construct(
                            Manager $eventManager,
                            \Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context $context,
                            CollectionFactory $customerCollectionFactory,
                            SubscriptionCollectionFactory $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
                            SubscriptionType $subscriptionTypeSource, StoreRepository $storeRepository,
                            CustomerRepository $customerRepository,
                            SubscriptionModelFactory $subscriptionModelFactory,
                            CustomerBalanceRepositoryInterface $customerBalanceRepository,
                            array $data = [],
                            ?JsonHelper $jsonHelper = null, ?DirectoryHelper $directoryHelper = null) {
    parent::__construct($eventManager);
    $this->customerCollectionFactory = $customerCollectionFactory;
    $this->subscriptionCollectionFactory = $subscriptionCollectionFactory;
    $this->subscriptionTypeSource = $subscriptionTypeSource;
    $this->storeRepository = $storeRepository;
    $this->customerRepository = $customerRepository;
    $this->subscriptionModelFactory = $subscriptionModelFactory;
    $this->customerBalanceRepository = $customerBalanceRepository;
}

public function getCustomerPoints($customerId){
    dump($customerId);
    return $this->customerBalanceRepository->getBalanceByCustomerId((int)$customerId);
}

Then I wrote a class Test. This is what I came up with
class SubscriptionTest extends \PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase {


protected $customerAction;


/**
 * Set up
 *
 * @return void
 */
protected function setUp(): void
{
    $eventManager = $this->createMock(Manager::class);
    $context = $this->createMock(\Magento\Backend\Block\Template\Context::class);
    $customerCollectionFactory = $this->createMock(CustomerCollectionFactory::class);
    $subscriptionCollectionFactory = $this->createMock(SubscriptionCollectionFactory::class);
    $subscriptionTypeSource = $this->createMock(SubscriptionTypeSource::class);
    $storeRepository = $this->createMock(StoreRepository::class);
    $customerRepository = $this->createMock(CustomerRepository::class);
    $subscriptionModelFactory = $this->createMock(SubscriptionModelFactory::class);
    $customerBalanceRepository = $this->createMock(CustomerBalanceRepositoryInterface::class);

    $this->customerAction = new CustomerAction(
        $eventManager,
        $context,
        $customerCollectionFactory,
        $subscriptionCollectionFactory,
        $subscriptionTypeSource,
        $storeRepository,
        $customerRepository,
        $subscriptionModelFactory,
        $customerBalanceRepository
    );
}

public function testGetCustomerPoints() {
    $expectedPoints = (float)0.0;
    $customerId = 18227;
    $this->assertEquals($expectedPoints,$this->customerAction->getCustomerPoints($customerId));

    $customerId = 18226;
    $this->assertNotEquals($expectedPoints,$this->customerAction->getCustomerPoints($customerId));
}

}
Here are my observation...first customer id has 0 points and pass the test successfully...but to check if it wasn't a fake result...I tried to check with a customer who have points...and voila...the method still returns 0 as a result.
Which is odd cause i'm 100 % sure it can't return 0 as it's the only customer I have who have points on his account.
So I guess there is still something escaping my control in the database process.
Which is super odd too is that if I dump into the customerAction class the dump is getting properly the customerId...but if I want to go deeper in the subfunctions...the dumps are not appearing...like if the code wasn't really executed...this is really confusing.

Some thoughts about TDD you may skip
First of all, a simple PHPUnit test doesn't cover interaction with database, since it only tests the behavior of the code. For this purpose you may need to use integration tests (PHPUnit based) or Multi Functional Testing Framework (Selenium based), which Magento provides out-of-the-box.
As you mention the TDD, you should understand that it is not about testing the entire method, but about testing the each part of the code just before you writing it. Your tests must work correctly even without a database.
Simplified typical scenario:
You need to write a class A which will be an Observer whose main purpose will be to change the price of a product based on some conditions.

Create test to call this class and run the execute method.
Create the A class and the execute method inside.
Mock some condition, input and output data to compare.
Run test, it will fail due to the lack of logic in the method execute.
Add some logic and return to 4, repeat.

Let's move on to your scenario
It looks like the best way to achieve your goals is with a built-in integration testing mechanism.
All operations described here must be performed on the same server where Magento was installed and running as it requires a production environment including a database. If you want to run integration tests on your local installation, you must first install the same Magento instance and ensure that it works (including database functionality and basic functionality of all installed modules). It must be configured so that some of the settings can be transferred to the test one (usually these are required settings, but in our example we skip this).
1. Prepare configuration

Create phpunit configuration for your own tests. By default we have one example config that runs ALL integration tests in Magento, we don't need them so we must remove them:
cp ./dev/tests/integration/phpunit.xml.dist ./dev/tests/integration/stack_phpunit.xml
This file will be used for our module tests ONLY. Your file should look similar, but don't forget to change the testsuites node.
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <phpunit xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="https://schema.phpunit.de/9.3/phpunit.xsd"
             colors="true"
             columns="max"
             beStrictAboutTestsThatDoNotTestAnything="false"
             bootstrap="./framework/bootstrap.php"
             stderr="true"
             testSuiteLoaderClass="Magento\TestFramework\SuiteLoader"
             testSuiteLoaderFile="framework/Magento/TestFramework/SuiteLoader.php">
        <coverage>
            <include>
                <directory suffix=".php">../../../app/code/Magento</directory>
                <directory suffix=".php">../../../lib/internal/Magento</directory>
            </include>
            <exclude>
                <directory>../../../app/code/*/*/Test</directory>
                <directory>../../../lib/internal/*/*/Test</directory>
                <directory>../../../lib/internal/*/*/*/Test</directory>
                <directory>../../../setup/src/*/*/Test</directory>
            </exclude>
        </coverage>
        <!-- Test suites definition -->
        <testsuites>
            <testsuite name="Your test suite">
                <directory>../../../app/code/MageWorx/OpenAI/Test/Integration</directory>
            </testsuite>
        </testsuites>
        <php>
            <includePath>.</includePath>
            <includePath>testsuite</includePath>
            <ini name="date.timezone" value="America/Los_Angeles"/>
            <ini name="xdebug.max_nesting_level" value="200"/>
            <const name="TESTS_INSTALL_CONFIG_FILE" value="etc/install-config-mysql.php"/>
            <const name="TESTS_POST_INSTALL_SETUP_COMMAND_CONFIG_FILE" value="etc/post-install-setup-command-config.php"/>
            <const name="TESTS_GLOBAL_CONFIG_FILE" value="etc/config-global.php"/>
            <const name="TESTS_GLOBAL_CONFIG_DIR" value="../../../app/etc"/>
            <const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="enabled"/>
            <const name="TESTS_MEM_LEAK_LIMIT" value=""/>
            <const name="TESTS_EXTRA_VERBOSE_LOG" value="1"/>
            <const name="TESTS_MAGENTO_MODE" value="developer"/>
            <const name="TESTS_ERROR_LOG_LISTENER_LEVEL" value="-1"/>
            <const name="USE_OVERRIDE_CONFIG" value="enabled"/>
        </php>
        <listeners>
            <listener class="Magento\TestFramework\Event\PhpUnit"/>
            <listener class="Magento\TestFramework\ErrorLog\Listener"/>
        </listeners>
        <extensions>
            <extension class="Qameta\Allure\PHPUnit\AllureExtension">
                <arguments>
                    <string>allure/allure.config.php</string>
                </arguments>
            </extension>
        </extensions>
    </phpunit>

I removed all comments and junk data and added only one test suite (my own):
<testsuites>
    <testsuite name="Your test suite">
        <directory>../../../app/code/MageWorx/OpenAI/Test/Integration</directory>
    </testsuite>
</testsuites>

2. Copy and update the configuration files for db and config (optional):

cp ./dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php.dist ./dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php

Open the file and add information about your environment. Here's an example:
<?php
return [
    'db-host'           => 'localhost',
    'db-user'           => 'magento2_test_user',
    'db-password'       => 'ftYx4pm6^x9.&^hB',
    'db-name'           => 'magento_integration_tests',
    'db-prefix'         => '',
    'backend-frontname' => 'backend',
    'admin-user'        => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_NAME,
    'admin-password'    => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    'admin-email'       => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_EMAIL,
    'admin-firstname'   => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_FIRSTNAME,
    'admin-lastname'    => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_LASTNAME,
    'use-secure'        => '0',
    'use-secure-admin'  => '0'
];

Note: database and user must be created manually! This database should be kept separate from the actual database as it can be deleted without your permission. This is for testing purposes only.

cp ./dev/tests/integration/etc/config-global.php.dist ./dev/tests/integration/etc/config-global.php

Open the file and add your configuration information. Here's an example:
<?php
return [
    'customer/password/limit_password_reset_requests_method' => 0,
    'admin/security/admin_account_sharing' => 1,
    'admin/security/limit_password_reset_requests_method' => 0,
];

3. Create integration test

For example I will create and use app/code/MageWorx/OpenAI/Test/Integration/QueueProcessCreationTest.php which should create one process, save it (testRegisterProcess) and load it (testLoadProcessByCode) to confirm that database operations work fine.
<?php
declare(strict_types = 1);

namespace MageWorx\OpenAI\Test\Integration;

use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;
use MageWorx\OpenAI\Api\Data\QueueProcessInterface;
use MageWorx\OpenAI\Model\Queue\QueueProcessManagement;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

/**
 * @magentoDbIsolation disabled
 */
class QueueProcessCreationTest extends TestCase
{
    private $queueProcessManagement;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->queueProcessManagement = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(QueueProcessManagement::class);
    }

    public function testRegisterProcess()
    {
        $code           = 'test_code';
        $type           = 'test_type';
        $name           = 'Test Process';
        $module         = 'Test_Module';
        $size           = 10;
        $additionalData = ['key' => 'value'];

        $process = $this->queueProcessManagement->registerProcess($code, $type, $name, $module, $size, $additionalData);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(QueueProcessInterface::class, $process);
        $this->assertEquals($code, $process->getCode());
        $this->assertEquals($type, $process->getType());
        $this->assertEquals($name, $process->getName());
        $this->assertEquals($module, $process->getModule());
        $this->assertEquals($size, $process->getSize());
        $this->assertEquals(json_encode($additionalData), $process->getAdditionalData());

        $this->testLoadProcessByCode($code);

        return $code;
    }

    /**
     * @depends testRegisterProcess
     */
    public function testLoadProcessByCode(string $code)
    {
        $process = $this->queueProcessManagement->getExistingProcessByCode($code);

        $this->assertInstanceOf(QueueProcessInterface::class, $process);
        $this->assertEquals($code, $process->getCode());
        $this->assertEquals('test_type', $process->getType());
        $this->assertEquals('Test Process', $process->getName());
        $this->assertEquals('Test_Module', $process->getModule());
        $this->assertEquals(10, $process->getSize());
        $this->assertEquals(json_encode(['key' => 'value']), $process->getAdditionalData());
    }
}

Important notes:

We use the @magentoDbIsolation disabled for the test suite to prevent the transaction from being rolled back after each test completes. Without this, you will get an error in the second test because after the first one completes, the test framework will rollback all transactions, resulting in missing data.
We use the @depends testRegisterProcess in the PHPDoc of second test to pass the result of the first test (the $code) to the second (dependent) test as an argument. This links our tests but separates the testing logic. If you want you can write all your test logic in one method, but I strongly advise you not to do this because it will mess up all your code and make it unclear for other developers.

4. Run your tests

Go to the ./dev/tests/integration directory and run PHPUnit as follows:
../../../vendor/bin/phpunit -v -c ../../../dev/tests/integration/stack_phpunit.xml

where the -c /path/to/config.xml is your custom configuration file to use and the -v (before the -c) is for verbose output to get additional information in case something goes wrong.
This can take few minutes to complete based on your system. Result will be look like this:

root@localhost /v/w/m/d/t/integration# ../../../vendor/bin/phpunit -v -c ../../../dev/tests/integration/stack_phpunit.xml
PHPUnit 9.6.15 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

Runtime:       PHP 8.2.5
Configuration: ../../../dev/tests/integration/stack_phpunit.xml
Warning:       Using a custom test suite loader is deprecated

..                                                                                                                                         2 / 2 (100%)

Time: 00:16.342, Memory: 133.50 MB

OK (2 tests, 21 assertions)

=== Memory Usage System Stats ===
Memory usage (OS):    174.17M (138.78% of 125.50M reported by PHP)
Estimated memory leak:    48.67M (27.94% of used memory)

root@localhost /v/w/m/d/t/integration#


Note: If you want to manually check the data in the database after the test completes, change this setting in the configuration:
<const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="enabled"/>

to disabled:
<const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="disabled"/>

This way the framework will save the data after each run, but be careful as this can lead to errors! (data will not be cleared before launch)
If you have any questions, write them in the comments, I will try to help.

Haven't got the time to test yet, I will have to update my docker to add an extra database to test it i guess. But seems complete and relevant. Thanks.

Thanks a lot for your assistance, to avoid messing with the original issue and adding too much information I created a second topic for the real implementation of your answer, but i'm kinda struggling with an error I don't really get : https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/374634/tdd-units-test-and-integration-tests-part-two

I am new to this subject as well, but I would start with by looking at how Magento writes its own tests.
For your first use case, there seems to be a few tests Magento does :

For base price : \Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Model\Product\Price\BasePriceStorageTest::testUpdate
For special price : \Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Model\Product\Price\SpecialPriceStorageTest::testUpdate

For each of them, there are also tests to ensure error cases work too (invalid format, exceptions, ...).
There are more examples about prices in the following folder :

vendor/magento/module-catalog/Test/Unit/Model/Product/Price

For the second use case, there also seems to be an existing method performing this test :

\Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Model\ProductRepositoryTest::testSaveNew

For your third use case, here is the method which looks the most like what you need :

\Magento\Catalog\Test\Unit\Model\ProductRepositoryTest::testSaveExisting

If you are looking to test the existing features of Magento, there are already a lot of tests done. They can be used as an example to do yours on your own modules.
Some well-known editors also seems to have more tests in their modules, which might also be used as an example, and sometimes be less complicated and less overwhelming than the thousands of unit tests of Magento.

Sadly i'm more looking to test custom entities than existing magento ones; that being said looking at how magento does things seems to be a good start. My bad for using product as key word in the question but I've assumed may be wrongly that a product would act like any other entity to make a test.

Just updated the issue with an exemple from my own...and I'm even more confused that in the begenning ^^
