TDD : Units Test And Integration Tests : Part Two
This question comes as a complement from issue already posted in  Magento 2 and TDD good practices to implement tests
After I implemented my own understanding of the solution provided.
I'm getting the error :
vendor/bin/phpunit -v -c dev/tests/integration/datasolution_phpunit.xml 
Exception: Could not connect to the Amqp Server.

In InstallCommand.php line 282:

  [InvalidArgumentException]
  Parameter validation failed


Exception trace:
  at /var/www/magento/setup/src/Magento/Setup/Console/Command/InstallCommand.php:282
 Magento\Setup\Console\Command\InstallCommand->initialize() at /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php:264
 Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run() at /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:1040
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand() at /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:301
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun() at /var/www/magento/vendor/magento/framework/Console/Cli.php:116
 Magento\Framework\Console\Cli->doRun() at /var/www/magento/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php:171
 Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run() at /var/www/magento/bin/magento:23


I'm not sure to understand where the error comes from...I'm also wondering if it's really normal that it's playing the setup script; nut i guess it's kinda installing magento on the new database...so I guess it is ? Unsure though. Thanks for any kind of assistance !
Anyway, here is the detail of what i did.
As a start, I created a bunch of shell script setting ma database and configuration files automatically so as I can use the sample example on any docker project...but I'll pass the details and show the results.
As a resume I have my custom file xml unit file automatically generated

dev/tests/integration/aims_phpunit.xml

With his custom test suites
<testsuite name="Your test suite">
    <directory>../../../app/code/Aims/Testing/Test/Integration</directory>
</testsuite>

I also created a custom database with users and filled these data inside.

dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php

return [
    'db-host' => 'db.nes.internal',
    'db-user' => 'magento_test_user',
    'db-password' => 'magento_test_pwd',
    'db-name' => 'magento_test',
    'db-prefix' => '',
    'backend-frontname' => 'backend',
    'search-engine' => 'opensearch',
    'opensearch-host' => 'localhost',
    'opensearch-port' => 9200,
    'admin-user' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_NAME,
    'admin-password' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    'admin-email' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_EMAIL,
    'admin-firstname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_FIRSTNAME,
    'admin-lastname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_LASTNAME,
    'amqp-host' => 'localhost',
    'amqp-port' => '5672',
    'amqp-user' => 'guest',
    'amqp-password' => 'guest',
    'consumers-wait-for-messages' => '0',
];

Db and user being created by following script (but right now witht the test i'm doing there is still no interaction with data base)
#!/bin/bash

DB_NAME="magento_test"
DB_USER="magento_test_user"
DB_PASSWORD="magento_test_pwd"

echo "Configure database test";

echo "Checking if database '$DB_NAME' exists..."

if mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "USE $DB_NAME"; then
    echo "Database '$DB_NAME' already exists. Skipping creation."
else
    echo "Database '$DB_NAME' does not exist. Creating database..."
    mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "CREATE DATABASE $DB_NAME;"
    echo "Database '$DB_NAME' created."
fi

echo "Checking if user '$DB_USER' exists..."
result=$(mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -N -s -e "SELECT 1 FROM mysql.user WHERE user = '$DB_USER'")
if [ "$result" = "1" ]; then
    echo "User '$DB_USER' already exists. Skipping user creation."
else
    echo "User '$DB_USER' does not exist. Creating user..."
    mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "CREATE USER '$DB_USER'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '$DB_PASSWORD';"
    echo "User '$DB_USER' created."
fi

echo "Granting privileges to user '$DB_USER' on database '$DB_NAME'..."
mysql -u root -p"$MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD" -e "GRANT ALL ON $DB_NAME.* TO '$DB_USER'@'%';"
echo "Privileges granted."

echo "End configuration database test";

Then I have the class subsject to the test which is quite simple as you will see
<?php

namespace Aims\Testing\Helper;

use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;
use Magento\Framework\App\Helper\Context;

class TestMethodsClass extends AbstractHelper
{

    protected $value;

    public function __construct(Context $context)
    {
        parent::__construct($context);
        $this->value = 0;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function add()
    {
        $this->value++;
        return $this->value;
    }

    /**
     * @return int
     */
    public function sub()
    {
        $this->value--;
        return $this->value;
    }

}


And finally; the test class itself
<?php

namespace Aims\Testing\Test\Integration;

use Magento\TestFramework\Helper\Bootstrap;
use Aims\Testing\Helper\TestMethodsClass;
use PHPUnit\Framework\TestCase;

class PocIntegrationTest extends TestCase
{
    private $helperClass;

    protected function setUp(): void
    {
        $this->helperClass = Bootstrap::getObjectManager()->get(TestMethodsClass::class);
    }

    public function testAddAndSub()
    {
        $resultOne = $this->helperClass->add();
        $expectedValue = 1;

        $resultTwo = $this->helperClass->add();
        $expectedValueTwo = 2;

        $resultThree = $this->helperClass->sub();
        $expectedValueThree = 1;

        $this->assertEquals($expectedValue, $resultOne);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedValueTwo, $resultTwo);
        $this->assertEquals($expectedValueThree, $resultThree);

    }


}


EDIT : If I remove the amqp config form the file the magento 2 install in starting before failign due to the table not being there...which is logic as it's a new database and we are running the install...makes no sense to me
Starting Magento installation:
File permissions check...
[Progress: 1 / 1655]
Required extensions check...
[Progress: 2 / 1655]
Enabling Maintenance Mode...
[Progress: 3 / 1655]
Installing deployment configuration...
[Progress: 4 / 1655]
Installing database schema:
In Mysql.php line 603:
  [Magento\Framework\DB\Adapter\TableNotFoundException (1146)]
  SQLSTATE[42S02]: Base table or view not found: 1146 Table 'magento_test.eav_entity_type' doesn't exist, query was: SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `eav_entity_type` AS `main_table`


Based on the error provided, your AMQP connection seems to be malfunctioning. First of all, you need to check if it's working correctly. You must use the same credentials as defined in your configuration:
'amqp-host' => 'localhost',
'amqp-port' => '5672',
'amqp-user' => 'guest',
'amqp-password' => 'guest',
'consumers-wait-for-messages' => '0',

Verify the RabbitMQ status.
In the system where the RabbitMQ installed locally you can use:
systemctl status rabbitmq-server

Or try this if you are using remote host (or docker container).
Run tests without RabbitMQ.
If you don't want to use RabbitMQ you can simply skip it, so remove the amqp part from your configuration file to make it similar to this one:

dev/tests/integration/etc/install-config-mysql.php

return [
    'db-host' => 'db.nes.internal',
    'db-user' => 'magento_test_user',
    'db-password' => 'magento_test_pwd',
    'db-name' => 'magento_test',
    'db-prefix' => '',
    'backend-frontname' => 'backend',
    'search-engine' => 'opensearch',
    'opensearch-host' => 'localhost',
    'opensearch-port' => 9200,
    'admin-user' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_NAME,
    'admin-password' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_PASSWORD,
    'admin-email' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_EMAIL,
    'admin-firstname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_FIRSTNAME,
    'admin-lastname' => \Magento\TestFramework\Bootstrap::ADMIN_LASTNAME
];

Regarding your question:

I'm also wondering if it's really normal that it's playing the setup script; nut i guess it's kinda installing magento on the new database...so I guess it is ?

yes, it is. If you are setting up the <const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="enabled"/> it will reinstall Magento from scratch on any new run. To prevent it from reinstalling you must disable this setting - <const name="TESTS_CLEANUP" value="disabled"/> so it will use specified Magento instance "as is", but you will be responsible for the changes.
Regarding your update (edit) to the question
It looks like the database wasn't cleaned up properly and this can cause schema installation errors, so try cleaning it up manually (drop all tables or drop the database and recreate it with a script) and then try running the tests again.
If that doesn't help, please provide the full aims_phpunit.xml code and your system info (version of Magento, php, mysql etc.). Then I'll try running similar tests locally.

I don't remember 100% but I think at some point I imported myself the database. So currently on my local I have my docker db used by the application, and a second db which is a copy with all tables and data that i aims to used for the test.  If I understand properly what you are saying, it means that dumping myself this database was the bad way. Although, considering it's a second database different from the dev one, I actually don't mind if data is persisted inside during the testing process. So may be I should remove the cleanup actually ? Sadly can't focus on this before some weeks again.

I'll use your answer as a reference for my next attempts, thank you :)

Hi, Thanks again, it works pixel perfect right now. Although I haven't test any database update but it's working as expected with the code I made there :) I had to make a few changes though. First, I had to use full path for the test suites directory instead of relative. And secondly, I had to remove allure extension (which I suspect not to be needed in my case anyway).

Successfully worked with database also. Just add to update once again to match my real search engine configuration a little bit specific with my docker..;but all good.
